# How do I plot the training loss vs iteration number in r for Logitboost?

Tags: r

I have this code I just don't know how to get the training loss as an output.

```
fit <- LogitBoost(Xtrain, Ytrain, nIter = 500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for checking the accuracy of your model using the confusionMatrix function from the caret package:

```
library(caTools)
library(caret)
data(iris)
Data  = iris[,-5]
Label = iris[, 5]

# basic interface
model = LogitBoost(Data, Label, nIter=20)
print(confusionMatrix(predict(model, Data, nIter= 2), Label)$overall[1])
Accuracy 
0.971831
```

You can iterate that with the number of iterations you want.